# Benefits of using Validate in Java over doing manual error checking?

Tags: java, validation, error-handling

I am modifying some code and I am seeing consistent use of "validate" for error checking.

What is the difference between `Validate.notNull(x, "x cannot be empty")` and `if(null != x){...}` and what are the advantages of one over the other?

EDIT: I am using org.apache.commons.lang.Validate

Comment: What is Validate? It seems to be some class of some unit test framework... Am I correct?

Comment: What the signature of the method `notNull`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit: assuming you are referring to org.apache.commons.lang.Validate

---

The first says that calling the method with a null parameter is entirely illegal, it was a coding mistake on the part of the programmer who used the method.

The second is just saying that there are different behaviours depending on if x is null or not.

It becomes just a readability issue if you're actually doing this:

```
if(null != x)
{
//...
} else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException( "x cannot be empty");
}
```

How long is the body of that if going to be?  Why is the consequence of calling the method illegally physically separated from the check for if it was called illegally?  As soon as you add some more parameters, that have various different legal states, this can get really hard for others to understand.  It is much friendlier to other programmers if you explicitly reject every invocation that is known to be absolutely illegal right at the start.

Comment: I didn't understand the question in this way, but I think your interpretation is valid! +1

Answer (score 0):

`Validate` does not belong to the Java API, you are probably using a framework or somebody else's class to do validations.

Regarding the benefits, it depends on what `Validate.notNull` is doing internally, hopefully it would be consistent with its name and would be doing only what is says, check if a value is not null. A benefit is that it allows you to specify an error message so you can reduce the verbosity of your code, but again it depends on what it does with that message, it could be adding them to a stack of messages or throwing an unchecked exception.